# how to set Enum in DropDownListFor and keep selectet item when back to this page in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

when use this code in firstPage and go to other page , and come back to this page with passing model to first page, selected value in DropDownList not found

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Supplementary.BloodGroup, EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(AzarWeb.Domain.HRM.ProvidingStaff.Core.Enumeration.BloodGroupEnum)), "please select one item", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

how to set selectet value in DropDownListFor when come back to this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways, depending on what are you doing.

If you are calling to your server controller, and on the return you want to "remember" dropdownlist previously selected value, you'll need to pass it to the view in the model.

The best option for this is to create the DropDownList control through a SelectList object passed in the model. One of the parameters of SelectList constructor is the currently selected value.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx

The other way around this is not having to remember anything because you don't reload your whole page. Depending how are you managing your webpage browsing, when you send info to your server you can use an AJAX call. Whith this the page isn't reloaded, so the already selected DropDownList doesn't lose it's current value after server returns.